# Check a bank legitimate

Tags: income-tax, irs, bank-account, scams, international

I would like to know if Habib Union offshore bank is legit. They had ask me to pay income tax ($5250) and IMF registering ($25500) to unlock my account.

And now they asking to pay for IRA Clearance certificate ($48k, half will be refunded later) for my possible E-transfer. Payment have to be made in bitcoins.

The address: Valikonagi Cad. No3/ 34378 Nisantasi/ Istanbul
Tel; +09(212)5245608

Answer (score 16):

I'm afraid that there is absolutely no way this is legitimate. You've lost the money you've already sent them, do not send any more. Report them with any correspondence you have to local law enforcement, block and cease communicating with them. And look out for other scam attempts in the future, you've unfortunately shown that you are an easy mark now.